# Variable contain undef value in perl

Tags: regex, perl, undefined-behavior, removing-whitespace

My file contain:

```
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REPLY.QUEUE)      TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.33.20)                       BOQNAME( )

AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE)    TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.32.37)                       BOQNAME( )

AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.MESSAGE.ASSOCIATION.QUEUE)
   TYPE(QLOCAL)                            ACCTQ(QMGR)
   ALTDATE(2016-08-01)                     ALTTIME(18.32.37)

AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.PENDING.DATATYPE.REPLY)        TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.33.20)                       BOQNAME( )
```

I want to extract data from QUEUE option, which suppose to output as below,

```
SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REPLY.QUEUE 
SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE 
SYSTEM.MESSAGE.ASSOCIATION.QUEUE
SYSTEM.PENDING.DATATYPE.REPLY
```

I wrote a code to obtain this output,

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (CHS_OUT, "cat test.txt|");
while (<CHS_OUT>) {

        my ($QName) = /QUEUE\(([^()]+)\)/;
        chomp($QName);

        print "$QName \n";

}
```

However, received below warnings,

> Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 1.   SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REPLY.QUEUE 
>   Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 3.   Use of uninitialized value
>   $QName in concatenation (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,
>    line 4.   Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation
>   (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,  line 5.   Use of
>   uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 6.   SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE
>   Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 8.   Use of uninitialized value
>   $QName in concatenation (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,
>    line 9.   Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation
>   (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,  line 10.   Use of
>   uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 11.
>   SYSTEM.MESSAGE.ASSOCIATION.QUEUE  Use of uninitialized value $QName in
>   concatenation (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,  line 13.
>   Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 14.   Use of uninitialized value
>   $QName in concatenation (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,
>    line 15.   Use of uninitialized value $QName in
>   concatenation (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,  line 16.
>   SYSTEM.PENDING.DATATYPE.REPLY  Use of uninitialized value $QName in
>   concatenation (.) or string at test_str.pl line 19,  line 18.
>   Use of uninitialized value $QName in concatenation (.) or string at
>   test_str.pl line 19,  line 19.

If I remove `use strict` and `use warnings` in my code, it will success, however there are multiple whitespace below the value, output as below,

```
SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REPLY.QUEUE 




SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE 




SYSTEM.MESSAGE.ASSOCIATION.QUEUE 




SYSTEM.PENDING.DATATYPE.REPLY
```

This output are not what I plan to have because it have multiple white-space line under the value, which this white-space perl assume as undef value.

I suppose to have output as below which is without whitespace in each line,

```
SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REPLY.QUEUE 
SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE 
SYSTEM.MESSAGE.ASSOCIATION.QUEUE
SYSTEM.PENDING.DATATYPE.REPLY
```

Is there any possibility I can use `next` to make perl ignore to process undef value?

Comment: You get this message for each line that not conatins your pattern

Comment: This has already been answered on your other question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this undefined messge for every line that does not contain "Queue(".
So you have to check it:

```
while (<CHS_OUT>) {
        my ($QName) = /QUEUE\(([^()]+)\)/;
        if ($QName){ 
           print "$QName \n";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens for this answer, however is there any way that we can avoid perl process every line that does not contain the QUEUE option?

Comment: @Azizul If there is such function i never used it

Comment: There is no need for the `chomp` or the separate variable. The entire block may be written as `print "$1\n" if /QUEUE\(([^()]+)\)/`

Comment: @Borodin Yes it can be if there is no other logic wich was removed to make a minimal example. But i think it is no reason to downvote

Comment: The OP is very clear about their requirement.

Comment: @Borodin So you think it is downvoted because of coding style?

Comment: I can't say, but the layout is poor as well so it's a bit sloppy over all.

Comment: @Azizul But how should Perl figure out which lines do not contain QUEUE and must be skipped? It can do so only by watching (read: processing) them.